# Angular Material Progress Bar not getting called

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use angular material progress bar, i have used this code in app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatProgressBarModule } from '@angular/material/progress-bar';

  ],
  imports: [
    MatProgressBarModule
  ],
```

calling progress bar like this in app.component.html

```
 <mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" value="100"></mat-progress-bar>
```

it is working in this component but i want to call in other component using the same code but not getting called.

Getting this error:

> mat-progress-bar is not a known element

Comment: Is the component in app module? Or another module?

Comment: @Mustafa No it is in different component

Comment: Did you add this?  ```ng add @angular/material```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the other component is in a different module then you must include MatProgressBarModule in that module's imports array.